# Escaping reserved keywords in dbunit for DB2

Tags: java, sql, db2, keyword, dbunit

DBUnit is throwing an exception when trying to run an insert statement on an in-memory DB2 database:

```java
org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "HOUR" at line 1, column 45.
```

I realize that "HOUR" is a reserved keyword in DB2 but I'm not sure how to get dbunit to escape this reserved keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found that the default escape pattern for dbunit is the null string, so dbunit recognized the reserved keyword and tried to escape it with a null string. To change this, I used the following to change the escape pattern for reserved keywords and now it's working:

```java
dbunitConn.getConfig().setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_ESCAPE_PATTERN, "\"?\"");
```

Comment: `setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_ESCAPE_PATTERN, "\`?\`");` worked for MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You could try using properties on database configurations :

```
DatabaseConfig config = connection.getConfig();
config.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_ESCAPE_PATTERN, "[HOUR]");
```